# Convert a Hashmap string into an array using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I am using an API which returns data as a string in the following format:

```
{"domain.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}
```

I want to put this result in to a multi-dimensional PHP array, but since the input is a string, I can't think of a convenient way to convert this.

Is there a function that can automatically parse this data into an array as desired?

Comment: Yes: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/rOsaxH

Comment: Same solution, but a JSON file is not quite the same as a Hashmap. I couldn't find a duplicate by searching by what I thought I was looking for, so if nothing else the wording of this question will be useful to others.

Comment: @monkeymatrix: Does the API explicitly state that the format of the data is a (serialized) hashmap rather than JSON?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes it does.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's because the data that's returned doesn't *necessarily* conform to the JSON spec (hence, not *be* JSON). You'll probably be able to `json_decode()` it most of the time as others have said, but you should still be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `JSON`, simple enough:

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [domain.com] => Array
        (
            [status] => available
            [classkey] => domcno
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$j = '{"domain.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}';
$d = json_decode($j,true);

print_r($d);
```